# laravel- request empty in controller using ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am using laravel 6.0 and i am building crud application. I have following jquery code in view file

```
function updaterecord(id) {
        $('#modalupdate').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'update/'+id,
                method: 'post',
                success: function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                }
            })
        });
    }
```

And this is the code in controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id='') {
            $country = $request->input('countryname');
            $sortname = $request->input('sortname');
            $phonecode = $request->input('phonecode');
            //return $country.$sortname.$phonecode;
        return $request;
//            DB::table('countries')->where('id',$id)->update(
//                [
//                    'name' => $country,
//                    'sortname' => $sortname,
//                    'phonecode' => $phonecode,
//                ]);
    }
```

The problem is $request returns empty.
If I don't use ajax then I am getting all input values. But I dont know why its not working for ajax request. Also I have added this line in view file

```
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{!! csrf_token() !!}'
        }
    });
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: But your ajax call is not sending any data... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Open the browser console and check the error on the network tab, It definitely returns an error if exists.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing your form data. Try this:

```
function updaterecord(id) {
    $('#modalupdate').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update/' + id,
            method: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize();
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: i added data: $(this).serialize() but i am getting blank output

Comment: check if the control really comes to the submit handler and then check header body in network tab if the form data is being sent or not.

Comment: No. in request headers menu cookie, x-csrf-token, x-requested-with is present but i dont see input parameters

Comment: @SanketKulkarni, you need to show the exact code that you are trying or at least correct. It's hard to guess what you are using or not.

Comment: @jogesh_pi ok i have uploaded  code to http://ge.tt/4SBchyz2 please download it and tell me what is the problem ...please help me

Answer (score 0):

laravel by default does not send raw data , you have to convert your data to json, the best practice is :

```
return response()->json([
   'data' => $request  
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code for example and see if you get any hint.

```
   function updaterecord(id) {
    $('#modalupdate').on('submit', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'update/' + id,
        method: 'post',
        data: {'countryname' : 'India','sortname' : 'Sort Name', 'phonecode' : '022'};
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
      })
  });
  }
```

See if you are getting any response.

Comment: Yeah..i am getting all the values..but why it is not working if i write data: $(this).serialize(); please tell me

Comment: @SanketKulkarni Try form id instead, `$('#form_id').serialize()'`. Not sure why `$(this).serialize()'` not working, but I`ll post if I can figure out something.